# asp.net SiteMapPath with 'friendly urls' does not display

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sitemap

I've inherited a project with a SiteMapPath control, populated from a web.sitemap

Given the url /Admin/ControlPanel/Sku/Edit/1234 the breadcrumb disappears because there is not specific entry in the .sitemap for that url. This is a problem because the user cannot easily return to the Admin, Control Panel or Sku pages.

It doesn't appear to like wildcards, eg: `<siteMapNode url="/Admin/ControlPanel/Sku/Edit/*"`

How can I have the sitemap still display the breadcrumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done.
In they end I used a pragmatic workaround as I had to move on.

Given a url that failed to match:

```
If SiteMap.CurrentNode Is Nothing Then
  '- write out a home baked breadcrumb by parsing the url
  '- eg: Admin > ControlPanel > Sku
  '- which at least allowed a used in /Admin/ControlPanel.Sku/Edit/1234 to get back to the previous pages.
End If
```